# Error: "The provided key element does not match the schema" in DynamoDB batchWrite operation

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm facing an issue with the `batchWrite` operation in AWS DynamoDB. When I attempt to insert multiple items into a DynamoDB table using the following code snippet, I receive the error message: *"The provided key element does not match the schema"*.

```js
module.exports.saveToDynamoDB = async (myData) => {
  const tableName = process.env.MY_TABLE;

  const putRequests = myData.map((data) => ({
    PutRequest: {
      Item: AWS.DynamoDB.Converter.marshall(data),
    },
  }));

  const params = {
    RequestItems: {
      [tableName]: putRequests,
    },
  };

  try {
    await dynamoDb.batchWrite(params).promise();

    return {
      status: 'SUCCESS',
      message: `${myData.length} data saved to the database`,
    };

  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(error.message);
  }
};
```

Could someone please help me understand how I can use the marshall() function correctly to ensure DynamoDB-friendly notation for numeric values?

The `AWS.DynamoDB.Converter.marshall()` function appears to treat numeric values as strings and wraps them with quotation marks. This results in the mentioned error.

For example when myData is:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "first",
        "rating": 100
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "second",
        "rating": 99
    }
]
```

I get this:

```
{
  "RequestItems": {
    "myTable": [
      {
        "PutRequest": {
          "Item": {
            "id": {
              "N": "1"
            },
            "name": {
              "S": "first"
            },
            "rating": {
              "N": "100"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "PutRequest": {
          "Item": {
            "id": {
              "N": "2"
            },
            "name": {
              "S": "second"
            },
            "rating": {
              "N": "99"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

instead of having something like `"N": 1`.

Comment: Hi, what are the partition keys, sort keys and indexes defined in the table? What are the attributes referenced by this keys too? If you are using `IAC`, can you share a bit of the code defining the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The AWS.DynamoDB.Converter.marshall() function appears to treat numeric values as strings and wraps them with quotation marks. This results in the mentioned error.

This is correct, and is exactly how DynamoDB JSON syntax is.

You don't show how you create your client `dynamoaDb` which I'm guessing is `DocumentClient`? In which case you should not marshall.

If my assumption is wrong, please share the output of DescribeTable.

```
const putRequests = myData.map((data) => ({
    PutRequest: {
      Item: data,
    },
  }));
```

DocumentClient does the marshalling for you (that's it's purpose), so you just pass it plain JSON as you can see above.

Comment: Yes it is `DocumentClient` but what alternative method can I use to perform the batchWrite operation with the DynamoDB DocumentClient? I appreciate any suggestions or code examples you can provide.

Comment: Updated my answer to highlight what you need to do.

Comment: It worked perfectly. I really appreciate your guidance and the time you took to help me.